# Explanation of how to create circuit from transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, synthesis

So I'm in this lab course that must be taken concurrently with the main upper div circuits class, but we were assigned a lab that our professor did not explain and that the lab manual does not explain.

The task is to design a circuit with transfer function characteristics. I understand that the poles will dictate the roots of the denominator and the zeros are self explanatory, but I'm not sure how this actually plays into actual design.

I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through an example of how to do this, on say part a or part b.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I won't solve your professor's problem, but the key to understanding this is that capacitors and inductors have "resistance" with imaginary coefficients. The idea is to combine the resistance and the *reactance* as a complex sum $$ Z = R + jX,$$ that we call the **impedance** (and \$j\$ is the imaginary number \$\sqrt{-1}\$).

What is **reactance** \$X\$? It is the opposition of a circuit element to a change in current or voltage, due to that element's inductance or capacitance. By change, we mean how it reacts to an AC current (as opposed to a DC current). It can be further split into **capacitive reactance** \$X_C\$ and **inductive reactance** \$X_L\$. 
$$ Z = R + j(X_C + X_L)$$

Looking at an ideal capacitor, for instance, we know that $$ i = C \frac{dv}{dt},$$ so that if we generate an AC signal $$ v(t) = V_0 e^{j\omega t}, $$
then 
$$ i(t) = C\frac{d}{dt}\{V_0 e^{j\omega t}\} = C V_0\cdot j\omega\cdot e^{j\omega t}$$
So (keeping in mind \$v = iR\$, or the complex equivalent \$v = iZ\$) the impadance
$$ Z = jX_C = \frac{v(t)}{i(t)} = \frac{1}{j\omega C},$$
or
$$ X_C = \frac{1}{j^2\omega C} = -\frac{1}{\omega C} $$

Similarily, for an inductor, we have $$ v = L \frac{di}{dt}, $$
which leads to $$ jX_L = \frac{v(t)}{i(t)} = j L\omega, $$
or 
$$ X_L = L\omega.$$

So, now we can use passive components such as resistances, capacitors and inductors as *generalized* resistors, and we can create voltage transfer functions using simple voltage dividers. As an example, a \$1 \mu F\$ capacitor  followed by a resistor of \$1 k\Omega\$ will have transfer function (keeping in mind \$s = j\omega\$):

$$ \frac{Z_R}{Z_R + Z_C} = \frac{10^3}{10^3-j\frac{1}{\omega 10^{-6}}} = \frac{10^3\cdot j\omega}{10^3 j\omega + 10^{6}} = \frac{s}{s+0.001}$$

Comment: I understand what a transfer function is and what an impedance is. What I'm asking is: how do I work backwards to realize that there will be an inductor in this location of the circuit, a resistor in this other location, and a capacitor in that location? I know how to do the math, but I'm not sure for 2nd order circuits how to get what I want working backward.

Comment: It boils down to knowing voltage division and how you get zeros and poles from it. Also, if you know poles, e.g. \$s_1\$ and \$s_2\$, then you know that the function is \$\frac{P(s)}{Q(s)(s-s_1)(s-s_2)}\$.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you if you tried to find out how many topologies you could make using 3 elements only? For instance, L || (R+C), (L+R)||C, etc.